# Assign width attribute to columns in table based on index

Tags: html, css

Can I set a width attribute in css for each column in a table based on the column index? i.e.

```
table column_with_index_[0] {
    width: 100px;
}
table column_with_index_[1] {
    width: 200px;    
}
...
```

in my .css?

With just a simple table structure

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

etc...
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do something like this...

```
tr th:nth-child(1),
tr td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;}

tr th:nth-child(2),
tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 200px;}
```

But if you included something in your HTML like this...

```
<tr>
    <th data-index="1"></th>
    <th data-index="2"></th>
</tr>
```

Then you could target it like so...

```
tr th[data-index="1"] {
    width: 100px;}
```

CSS really can't count indexes, it can only target  what you specify.